# How to get specific character before character in vbscript

Tags: vb.net, split

I want to split a string in vbscript language.

The string contains : `shipping costs 10%`

I want to get the value before '%' but only the number.

I try with this but it doesn't work

```
spese = Split(spese,'%')(0)
```

Comment: vb.net and vbscript are 2 different languages. Please remove one of the tags. Also include the code that you tried and didn't work.

Comment: Ok I update the question

Comment: You want the last item resulting from splitting it at the spaces, and you want to trim the "%" off the end: `spese.Split({" "c}).Last().TrimEnd("%"c)`. (If that doesn't work then please edit the question to add the version of Visual Studio that you are using.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton why even split any of it?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Because it's easy (with some experience) and it's in line with the way the OP asked. You're welcome to write an answer explaining how to do it with a regex ;)

Comment: In vb.net the single quote is the comment character. To pass a Char to the String.Split function use "%"c. The c following the string tells the compiler that you intend a Char. You can also use CChar().

Comment: It would be `spese = spese.Split("%"c)(0)` using the .net String class method instead of the old Strings class from vb. But this would return an array with just one element; the string to the left of the %. Not what you want at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to retrieve everything before the `%` doesn't compile because you use conment signs as delimiter (`'`) and not (`"`)

After fixing that you also would have to cut out the value itself.

Regarding to the new conditions here is the solution in vb.net, assuming before the number there always is a blank:

```
  Dim myString As String
  myString = "shipping costs 10%"

  Dim tmp As String
  tmp = Left(myString, InStr(myString, "%") - 1)

  Dim result As String
  result = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - InStrRev(tmp, " "))
```

The solution of @AndrewMorton (see comments of your question) is much more elegant. You should use it.

Comment: but i want to get only the number, i want to get 10

Comment: You didn't explicitly wrote that. Let me take a look.

Comment: sorry i changed the question

Comment: @Mary: This is vbscript and executable. I came up to this question by the vbscript filter. Now I saw that maybe it's not vbscript, but vb.net.

Comment: Got it. Sorry. I have commented to OP to remove bogus tag. Deleting my comment.

Comment: I still is vbscript.

Comment: Could you update your solution to include *why* the OP code doesn't work; this helps other user's that may have the same issue and understand why.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I've done that now. But the development of the complete question and answer is a mess.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have added comments to the OP's question explaining why his solution didn't work.

Comment: @UnhandledException You're welcome to use my comment in your answer. Also, `spese.Substring(spese.LastIndexOf(" "c) + 1).TrimEnd({"%"c})` would be more efficient than the code in my comment. Or if you are feeling enthusiastic, the regex `\s+([0-9]+)%$` would work to capture those final digits before the % character.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you. I hate that my vote only brought you up to a 0, instead of a +1